# Android UTC Time Issue (I get incorrect time)

Tags: android, jodatime

I want to subtract two dates in Android project.

When I use the statement:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

It gives `2014-03-17T12:49:06.670Z` value instead of `2014-03-17T14:49:06.670Z` (this is my current time on Android device)

When I convert this `DateTime` (`2014-03-17T12:30:08.673+02:00`) to `UTC Time` (`2014-03-17T10:30:08.673Z`) it gives the correct result but not for `DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);`

What is wrong with `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, 2014-03-17T14:49:06.670Z is probably NOT your current time on Android device??? Did you mean 2014-03-17T14:49:06.670+02:00?

Comment: Yes it is! When I use "new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);" it gives result in "2014-03-17T14:49:06.670Z" format.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting your local time this way:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
```

This time is "your current time on Android device". More precisely DateTime calculates its fields with respect to a time zone. It means it will return UTC+2 if you are located in Eastern European Countries (Winter Time) or Wester European Countries (Summer time).

Answer (score 0):

On my PC nothing is wrong with `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`. The type `DateTime` internally stores the given time zone (here UTC) and uses it for the output of its method `toString()`, hence the UTC-string-format and not another alternative format with offset = +02:00.